# Android textColor selector

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-theme

I am trying to set up a selector for `TextView` textColor using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="?android:attr/textColorTertiary" />
    <item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

However, the color always appears to be `red` instead of those `theme colors`. If I put hardcoded color, everything seems to work fine. (ex. `<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#666666" />` ).

What is the problem and how to solve it? P.S. if anyone knows how to set theme's default disabled color for disabled item in the list, please share, that is what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I've got the same problem, reproducable on 4.1, but on newer versions seems fine (e.g. black on black theme). `?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse` looks red, while it shouldn't. I redefined `android:textColorPrimaryInverse`  in my theme to a custom selector but it's still red.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm trying to use a selector with ?android:attr/textColor and have similar issues

Answer (score -2):

As far as i can see you may have to use 3 states in a selector.

```
state enabled
state focused
state pressed
```

in exactly this order. This might help

Comment: the problem appears if I just only leave `<item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>` in my selector, so your answer doesn't help

Answer (score -2):

You used selector for what reason?
If you want to make your text of text view always red then no need of selector. Just define color in color.XML or in string.XML using add color.
And if you want to chanhe it on selection or focus than use the states.
    **state enabled**
    **state pressed**
    **state focused**
Than it will work as you need.